# Creating a Matrix with DocumentTermMatrix from the strings in a column in R (text-mining)

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix

The dataset looks as follows:

```
sentiment<-c(1, 1, 0)
review<-c("review1", "review2", "review3") #insert some reviews here
daamx<-data.frame(sentiment, review)
```

The sentiment column is a value that says if the review is positive or negative (1 or 0), I need this later in my assignment. The review column is the column where the reviews are stated. Daamx is a tsv file.

My goal is to get a matrix with the comments in the rows (each row contains 1 comment) and the words of all the comments in the columns. The table must represent with numbers how much each word occurs. Also I would like to set a max amount of words that is shown in the columns because I only need the 2000 most occuring or so.

My code so far:

```
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)

daamx_review<-daamx$review

#Changing the review column into a VectorSource and VCorpus
daamx_source<-VectorSource(daamx_review)
daamx_corpus<-VCorpus(daamx_source)

#Function
clean_corpus <- function(corpus){
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
  return(corpus)
}

#Using function
clean_daamx<-clean_corpus(daamx_corpus)

#Using DocumentTermMatrix and creating Matrix
daamx_tdm<-DocumentTermMatrix(clean_daamx,control = list())
daamx_m<-as.matrix(daamx_tdm)
```

After making the review column a VectorSource, a VCorpus and cleaning it with the clean_corpus function, I tried to put the clean_daamx in a DocumentTermMatrix and after that in a matrix. But the result I get now is a matrix with "Character(0)" in each row and only 30 words or so in the columns (only words that start with a and b it looks like).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of clean_daamx<-clean_docs(daamx_corpus) did you mean to put clean_daamx<-clean_corpus(daamx_corpus)

Comment: Yes, I had that in my code in R. Typed it wrong here...